# Namespace with colon as attribute of xml file in C#

Tags: c#, xml

I want to generate a xml code like below example:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Root xmlns ="abc.xyz.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://namespace">
</Root>
```

My C# code is like below:

```
XNamespace xsi = "http://namespace";
XDocument doc = new XDocument(
    new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", null),
    new XElement("Root",
    new XAttribute("xmlns", "abc.xyz.xsd"),
    new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "xsi", xsi)
);
```

This code gives error while saving. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What error did you get?

Comment: Never say that your code fails without saying how it fails. It's like telling your doctor that you have a pain without saying where it hurts.

Answer (score 3):

You can use with single namespace

```
        XNamespace xsi = "http://namespace";
        XDocument doc1 = new XDocument(
             new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", null),
             new XElement(xsi + "Root",
            new XAttribute("xmlns", "abc.xyz.xsd"),
            new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "xsi", "http://namespace"),
            new XElement(xsi + "Child",
                new XElement(xsi + "DifferentChild", "other content")
            )
        ));
```

See this for reference https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387075.aspx

The output will look like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsi:Root xmlns="abc.xyz.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://namespace">
  <xsi:Child>
    <xsi:DifferentChild>other content</xsi:DifferentChild>
  </xsi:Child>
</xsi:Root>
```

Answer (score 2):

You should add your `Root` element with namespace (namespace + "Root")  since you're using namespaces.

Like this:

```
XNamespace xsi = "http://namespace";
XNamespace ns = "abc.xyz.xsd";

XDocument doc = new XDocument(
    new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", null),
    new XElement(ns + "Root",
        new XAttribute("xmlns", ns),
        new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "xsi", xsi)));
```

See [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387075.aspx) concerning creation of documents having namespaces.